# Java 7 watchservice get file change offset

Tags: java, nio

I've just been playing around with the Java 7 WatchService for monitoring a file for change.

Here's a little bit of code I knocked up:

```
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    Path path = Paths.get("c:\\testing");

    path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

    while (true) {
        WatchKey key = watcher.take();

        for (WatchEvent event : key.pollEvents()) {
            System.out.println(event.kind() + ":" + event.context());
        }

        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

This seems to be working, and I get notifications as to when a file 'changethis.txt' gets modified.

However, in addition to being able to notify when a file changes, is there anyway of being notified as to the location within the file that the modification occurred?

I've had a look through the Java docs but I can't seem to find anything.

Is this possible using the WatchService, or would something custom have to be implemented?

Thanks

Comment: Such a thing is not possible with `WatchService`.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there anything within Java 7/NIO that might be able to do it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You will need to implement your own scan of the class before/after. A `WatchService` would not be ideal for this imo.

Comment: Can you just read the file before and after?

Comment: @AnubianNoob aside from the fact that this is far from elegant, it would not scale. Imagine a huge log file where each modification is one new line in the file. Reading the whole file each time is not performant at all...

Comment: If the file is updated with consecutive messages, and your application should not miss any of these messages, why don't you look into JMS. It is the standard, and therefore best practice, for messaging.

Comment: Well, if you want to detect *any* change (maybe at the beginning or somewhere in the middle of the file) it will definitely not scale, but I can hack a proof of concept for it (I have even started because I found it a fun problem to solve). If your files only change by content getting appended at the end (log files), it is a totally different problem than initially described by you. For the latter I have another solution in mind. So what should it be?

Comment: I personally am only interested in file appends, but the original question seems to be a bit more generic, so that _any_ change may also be interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what it is worth, I have hacked a little proof of concept which is able to

- detect added, modified and deleted files in a watched directory,
- displaying unified diffs for each change (also full diffs when files were added/deleted),
- keeping track of successive changes by keeping a shadow copy of the source directory,
- work in a user-defined rhythm (default is 5 seconds) so as not to print too many small diffs in a short period of time, but rather somewhat bigger ones once in a while.

There are several limitations which would be impediments in production environments:

- In order to not complicate the sample code more than necessary, subdirectories are copied at the beginning when the shadow directory is created (because I have recycled an existing method to create a deep directory copy), but ignored during runtime. Only files right below the watched directory are being monitored so as to avoid recursion.
- Your requirement not to use external libraries is not met because I really wanted to avoid re-inventing the wheel for unified diff creation.
- This solution's biggest advantage - it is able to detect changes anywhere in a text file, not only at the end of file like `tail -f` - is also its biggest disadvantage: Whenever a file changes it must be fully shadow-copied because otherwise the program cannot detect the subsequent change. So I would not recommend this solution for very big files.

How to build:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.scrum-master.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>SO_WatchServiceChangeLocationInFile</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.java-diff-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>diffutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Source code (sorry, a bit lengthy):

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import difflib.DiffUtils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

public class FileChangeWatcher {
    public static final String DEFAULT_WATCH_DIR = "watch-dir";
    public static final String DEFAULT_SHADOW_DIR = "shadow-dir";
    public static final int DEFAULT_WATCH_INTERVAL = 5;

    private Path watchDir;
    private Path shadowDir;
    private int watchInterval;
    private WatchService watchService;

    public FileChangeWatcher(Path watchDir, Path shadowDir, int watchInterval) throws IOException {
        this.watchDir = watchDir;
        this.shadowDir = shadowDir;
        this.watchInterval = watchInterval;
        watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    }

    public void run() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        prepareShadowDir();
        watchDir.register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);
        while (true) {
            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                Path oldFile = shadowDir.resolve((Path) event.context());
                Path newFile = watchDir.resolve((Path) event.context());
                List<String> oldContent;
                List<String> newContent;
                WatchEvent.Kind<?> eventType = event.kind();
                if (!(Files.isDirectory(newFile) || Files.isDirectory(oldFile))) {
                    if (eventType == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                        if (!Files.isDirectory(newFile))
                            Files.createFile(oldFile);
                    } else if (eventType == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                        oldContent = fileToLines(oldFile);
                        newContent = fileToLines(newFile);
                        printUnifiedDiff(newFile, oldFile, oldContent, newContent);
                        try {
                            Files.copy(newFile, oldFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else if (eventType == ENTRY_DELETE) {
                        try {
                            oldContent = fileToLines(oldFile);
                            newContent = new LinkedList<>();
                            printUnifiedDiff(newFile, oldFile, oldContent, newContent);
                            Files.deleteIfExists(oldFile);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            watchKey.reset();
            Thread.sleep(1000 * watchInterval);
        }
    }

    private void prepareShadowDir() throws IOException {
        recursiveDeleteDir(shadowDir);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Cleaning up shadow directory " + shadowDir);
                        recursiveDeleteDir(shadowDir);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        recursiveCopyDir(watchDir, shadowDir);
    }

    public static void recursiveDeleteDir(Path directory) throws IOException {
        if (!directory.toFile().exists())
            return;
        Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                Files.delete(file);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                Files.delete(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void recursiveCopyDir(final Path sourceDir, final Path targetDir) throws IOException {
        Files.walkFileTree(sourceDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                Files.copy(file, Paths.get(file.toString().replace(sourceDir.toString(), targetDir.toString())));
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(dir.toString().replace(sourceDir.toString(), targetDir.toString())));
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }

    private static List<String> fileToLines(Path path) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
        String line;
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.toFile()))) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                lines.add(line);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return lines;
    }

    private static void printUnifiedDiff(Path oldPath, Path newPath, List<String> oldContent, List<String> newContent) {
        List<String> diffLines = DiffUtils.generateUnifiedDiff(
            newPath.toString(),
            oldPath.toString(),
            oldContent,
            DiffUtils.diff(oldContent, newContent),
            3
        );
        System.out.println();
        for (String diffLine : diffLines)
            System.out.println(diffLine);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String watchDirName = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : DEFAULT_WATCH_DIR;
        String shadowDirName = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : DEFAULT_SHADOW_DIR;
        int watchInterval = args.length > 2 ? Integer.getInteger(args[2]) : DEFAULT_WATCH_INTERVAL;
        new FileChangeWatcher(Paths.get(watchDirName), Paths.get(shadowDirName), watchInterval).run();
    }
}
```

I recommend to use the default settings (e.g. use a source directory named "watch-dir") and play around with it for a while, watching the console output as you create and edit some text files in an editor. It helps understand the software's inner mechanics. If something goes wrong, e.g. within one 5 second rhythm a file is created but also quickly deleted again, there is nothing to copy or diff, so the program will just print a stack trace to `System.err`.

Comment: +1 and thanks for a good and comprehensive answer. I can understand the use of an external diff tool in this case. In my case, content would only be appended, so that a diff would be much easier. In any case, I do not really like the approach to simply have a copy of the file. I still hope there is a better solution, although I doubt there is :-)

Comment: Well, Simon, you are not the author of the question, and probably your "a diff would be easier" was a typo and you wanted to say "tail" instead of "diff". There also is a solution for this, and I guess we want to stay platform independent (e.g. there is no diff/tail preinstalled on Windows): https://github.com/dpillay/tail4j (untested)

Comment: Yeah, I know... So? :-) A diff on files where content is only appended is actually a tail I would say :-) Anyway, I will wait a few more days to see if there are more answers and if not, I will award the bounty to you.

Comment: Ah okay, you are not the author but have set a bounty anyway. I had no idea this was possible. Lesson learned.

Comment: Actually *Commons IO* is easier to use than the undocumented *tail4j* if you need a pure Java *tail* implementation. See my other answer.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, here is another answer as a variation of my previous one for changes at any file position (diff). Now the somewhat simpler case is files only being appended (tail).

**How to build:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.scrum-master.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>SO_WatchServiceChangeLocationInFile</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <!-- Use snapshot because of the UTF-8 problem in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-354 -->
            <version>2.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

As you can see, we use Apache Commons IO here. (Why a snapshot version? Follow the link in the XML comment if you are interested.)

**Source code:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer;
import org.apache.commons.io.input.TailerListenerAdapter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.*;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;

public class FileTailWatcher {
    public static final String DEFAULT_WATCH_DIR = "watch-dir";
    public static final int DEFAULT_WATCH_INTERVAL = 5;

    private Path watchDir;
    private int watchInterval;
    private WatchService watchService;

    public FileTailWatcher(Path watchDir, int watchInterval) throws IOException {
        if (!Files.isDirectory(watchDir))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path '" + watchDir + "' is not a directory");
        this.watchDir = watchDir;
        this.watchInterval = watchInterval;
        watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    }

    public static class MyTailerListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
        public void handle(String line) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    public void run() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirEntries = Files.newDirectoryStream(watchDir)) {
            for (Path file : dirEntries)
                createTailer(file);
        }
        watchDir.register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE);
        while (true) {
            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents())
                createTailer(watchDir.resolve((Path) event.context()));
            watchKey.reset();
            Thread.sleep(1000 * watchInterval);
        }
    }

    private Tailer createTailer(Path path) {
        if (Files.isDirectory(path))
            return null;
        System.out.println("Creating tailer: " + path);
        return Tailer.create(
            path.toFile(),             // File to be monitored
            Charset.defaultCharset(),  // Character set (available since Commons IO 2.5)
            new MyTailerListener(),    // What should happen for new tail events?
            1000,                      // Delay between checks in ms
            true,                      // Tail from end of file, not from beginning
            true,                      // Close & reopen files in between reads,
                                       // otherwise file is locked on Windows and cannot be deleted
            4096                       // Read buffer size
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String watchDirName = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : DEFAULT_WATCH_DIR;
        int watchInterval = args.length > 2 ? Integer.getInteger(args[2]) : DEFAULT_WATCH_INTERVAL;
        new FileTailWatcher(Paths.get(watchDirName), watchInterval).run();
    }
}
```

Now try appending to existing files and/or creating new ones. Everything will be printed to standard output. In a production environment you would maybe display multiple windows or tabs, one for each log file. Whatever...

@Simon: I hope this one suits your situation better than the more general case and is worth a bounty. `:-)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The combination of the two answers is great. You could consider to merge this one into the accepted one.

Comment: Nah, the use cases are too different and each answer by itself too verbose already. ;-)

Comment: Instead of using Tailer.create() method, Tailer tailer = new Tailer() would be better.Because Tailer.create() method may cause to call multiple time listener.handle() method.See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987713/1348364

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wrote this answer 5 years ago and only vaguely remember that it was the first and only time I ever used this library. So I am not an expert user, my answer was just a simple showcase on how it can be done. I had no problems with it, but everyone using the code from this answer feel free to do what @aekber suggested. :-)