# File of 2GB to be handled in Java

Tags: java, unix, file-io

I am working with a log file of size 2GB. When heap exceeds max limit, it throws OutOfMemory Error in my log file.

I want to simulate unix command 
**tail -20 native_stdout.log**

How do I do this in JAVA?

I cannot read line by line because it has thousands of lines, it is going to take lot of time.

And file I read is streaming one from SFTP serevr.

Comment: possibly answered here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/2356137](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356137/read-large-files-in-java)

Comment: Actually, answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121678/java-read-last-n-lines-of-a-huge-file

The simplest and most robust answer is the one that suggests using org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader from apache commons.io

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  You just need to remember the last 20 lines and once you reach the end, print them out, after that you need to print any additional lines.

Answer (score 2):

Apache commons has an Simple implementation of the unix "tail -f" functionality

[Tailer.html](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html)

[More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987170/apache-commons-io-tailer-example)

Comment: Question is about tail -num, not tail -f, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) to read a large file line by line.

Comment: That's wildly inefficient for a multi-gig file.

Comment: Hi, there are thousands of lines in log file, it is not desirable to read line by line. I need skip all lines but last 10