# Apache Tailer stops processing after 20 lines

Tags: java, apache-tailer

I have the following code,

```
public class Identifier extends TailerListenerAdapter {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        TailerListener listener = new Identifier();
        Tailer tailer = new Tailer(inputFile, listener, 500);
        tailer.run();
        while (true){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(String line) {
        super.handle(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

This is the total code I am using for the tailing service, I have a file which contains more that **100K** lines but the tailer only prints first **20** line.

What I am missing, I have also tried using the thread like this.

```
Thread tailerThread = new Thread(tailer);
tailerThread.start();
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987170/apache-commons-io-tailer-example

Comment: The answer that got the 10 up vote is just removing the loop as far as I understand, this thing stop the tailer after processing 20 lines.

Comment: It works fine of small file but not on the file which contains 1000k lines.