# How do I get updated contents of a txt file?

Tags: node.js

I would like to get updated content of a certain file, I was only able to get the updated file name.
The updated content will always be on a new line, appreciate all answers from now!

**NOTE:** I found a solution similar to what I need but it was in java.
[How to watch file for new content and retrieve that content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301511/how-to-watch-file-for-new-content-and-retrieve-that-content)

````
const md5 = require('md5');
require('log-timestamp');

const file = './file.txt';

console.log(`Watching for file changes on ${file}`);

let md5Previous = null;
let fsWait = false;
fs.watch(file, (event, filename) => {
  if (filename) {
    if (fsWait) return;
    fsWait = setTimeout(() => {
      fsWait = false;
    }, 100);
    const md5Current = md5(fs.readFileSync(buttonPressesLogFile));
    if (md5Current === md5Previous) {
      return;
    }
    md5Previous = md5Current;
    console.log(`${filename} file Changed`);
  }
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone searching for an answer, I used chokidar, read-last-lines, and EventEmitter to watch the file, and get the latest contents.